# BreezeJS Selecting ComplexType properties

Tags: javascript, breeze, durandal

I am running into an issue with Breeze and Durandal which is leading me to believe it may be a bug with Breeze or that I don't know the right syntax.

Here is my model (given that Address is just a simple ComplexType class)

```
public class Person {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Address MyAddress {get;set;}
}
```

And on the front-end with Breeze JS, I have the following:

```
EntityQuery.from('Person').select('id,name').orderBy('id');
```

The above line works perfect, but if I have:

```
EntityQuery.from('Person').select('id,name,myAddress').orderBy('id');
```

I get the error message that `Error retreiving data. deferred is not defined`

It looks like as though, you can't have the ComplexType property in the Select statement. Anyone else is running into this issue? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you show your address class as well?  Also how are you mapping a person to an address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: May 8, 2013 - This is now fixed in v 1.3.3

---

I've just confirmed that this is a bug - Your query syntax is correct ( you do not need an expand for complex types).  I will try to get this corrected in the next release and will post back here when it gets in.  And thanks for the repro :)

Comment: Thanks Jay for confirming it.