# BreezeJS Selecting Collection

Tags: breeze

This is related to the question in:
[BreezeJS Selecting ComplexType properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444122/breezejs-selecting-complextype-properties)

So:

```
public class Person {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Address MyAddress {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets {get;set;}
}
```

I Would like to call

```
EntityQuery.from('Person').select('id,name,pets').orderBy('id');
```

and map to a *personBrief* object.

I know there is a:

```
.toType("personBrief")
```

extension, but it doesn't seem to "find the object with that description" (Where could I define this?), and online help says no complex types supported.

Then I tried the *mapDtosToEntities()* function from [Jumpstart HotTowel tutorial](https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal/blob/master/SPAJumpStart/App/services/breeze.partial-entities.js)

This method seems to successfully map only non-array properties. Dto returned from the Breeze query has a *pets* collection correctly populated. I tried loop-pushing them into an *ko.observableArray* but event though it populates my new entity, breeze fails with a "Collection navigation property might not be set" error.

In the end I would like to create a Computed in the initializer that says.

```
personBrief.sumOfPetAges = ko.computed(function() {
            var sum = 0;

            person.pets().forEach(function (i) {
                sum += i.petAge();
            });
            return sum;
        });
```

Any ideea how I can keep the object graph after the projection? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you define `PersonBrief` as an EntityType? I'm betting not ... especially given that you called it "personBrief" in your sample. The `toType()` method is for casting a simple, flat, known EntityType. So I think you're heading off track a bit here.

Why not cast to `Person`? Sure some of the Person material is missing (as in CCJS ... although not in this particular example in which you are projecting all data properties). But it's very straightforward. Just write `toType('Person')`. Did you try that?

If you actually **want** to define such an EntityType on the client, you can [**as described in the docs**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format). If you do that, you can use the `toType()` cast to that type and Breeze will track it in cache. Of course saving such a thing back to the server is another matter. That's doable ... it could be a kind of DTO ... but you'll have to write the interception logic on the server and translate the data into real, server-side persistent entities and this path is beyond the scope of my answer.

Here is some code ... written off the top of my head ... but it should point you in the right direction. Note that I am assuming that `Pet` is an EntityType, not a ComplexType! At this moment Breeze does not support arrays of ComplexTypes (it will but it doesn't today).

```
   // Define a PersonBrief type for a given MetadataStore
   function addPersonBriefType(metadataStore) {
        var perType = metadataStore.getEntityType('Person');

        var type = new breeze.EntityType({
            shortName: 'PersonBrief',
            namespace: perType.namespace 
        });
        var idProperty = new breeze.DataProperty({
            nameOnServer: 'Id',
            dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32,
            isPartOfKey: true,
        });
        type.addProperty(idProperty);
        type.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({ nameOnServer: 'Name' }));

        // Here's how you define your Pets collection
        // I assume that you already have a Pet type in metadata and
        // it has an inverse navigation back to Person
        // Get the navigation property from Person to Pets
        var assoc = perType.getNavigationProperty('Pets');

        type.addProperty(new breeze.NavigationProperty({
            nameOnServer: 'Pets',
            isScalar: false, // it's a collection
            entityTypeName: assoc.entityType.name,
            foreignKeyNames: assoc.inverse.foreignKeyNames,
            associationName: assoc.associationName
        }));

        metadataStore.addEntityType(type);
        return type;
    }
```

I was able to do something like this with `EmployeePartial` in the *metadataTests.js* of the DocCode sample where the equivalent to `Pets` is `Orders`. The comparable projection query is this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Employees')
    .where('EmployeeID', 'eq', 1)
    .select('EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Orders')
    .toType('EmployeePartial')
```

Your `sumOfPetAges` computed should work because there is a `PersonBrief` type to supplement.

I am winging it myself to be sure. I know it works even if I can't swear by this particular bit of code that I've written here. Let us know how this goes for you.

p.s. While you should be able to navigate from `PersonBrief` to `Pets`, do not expect to navigate back from a `Pet` to a `PersonBrief`; that navigation property is not defined.

Comment: Thank you @Ward. Will try this way and let you know.

Comment: Got as far as executing the query and getting the mapping right. However if Pet has a _personId_ property and the _Person Person_ prop in the POCO definition would that qualify the Pet type as a ComplexType? I had this error on manager.executeQuery(query). `Error getting data. Property 'personId' of object [object Object] is not a function.`

Comment: I get that error when I deliberately misspell a Foreign Key name. Are you sure you spelled the property `personId` correctly. Capitalization matters and I can't remember if it must match the spelling of the client-side or server-side property (guessing client-side).

Comment: A type is a ComplexType if it has no existence independent of its parent type. ComplexTypes don't have keys. Navigation properties return real EntityTypes; all EntityTypes have a primary key (e.g., `PersonId`).

Comment: Yes, but doesn't the Pet object get deserialized independently from metadata by breeze (along with the _personId_ FK) when you specify the type.addProperty(NavigationProperty)? Or do I have to define a Pet object like I did for personBrief?

Comment: Yes, the Pet JSON data are mapped separately by Breeze into `Pet` entities based on a description of the `Pet` type in metadata. I was assuming that `Pet` is a CLR type that is part of your EF model and, therefore, is already defined in metadata (unlike `PersonBrief` which is a made-up type). Btw, have you considered just using `Person`. What is `PersonBrief` doing for you?

Comment: I gave up loading partially the object. I am loading the full Person and use expand. I couldn't figure out why the Pet object's FK was not correct. Plus, as you mentioned, it makes it more difficult to Save to EF.